# How to update timestamp value to date-time format in json file with the help of unix commands?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

```
{
        "cluster_name" : "c",
        "definition_name" : "hive_metastore_process",
        "firmness" : "HARD",
        "latest_timestamp" : 1498716914911,
        "maintenance_state" : "OFF",
        "original_timestamp" : 1498416757291,
        "service_name" : "HIVE",
        "state" : "CRITICAL",
      }
--
       : {
        "cluster_name" : "c",
        "definition_name" : "hive_server_process",
        "firmness" : "HARD",
        "latest_timestamp" : 1498716912904,
        "maintenance_state" : "OFF",
        "original_timestamp" : 1498419634610,
        "service_name" : "HIVE",
        "state" : "CRITICAL",
      }
```

I want to update original_timestamp to date format, What are unix commands can help to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

For dealing with json on the command line, `jq` is your friend.

```
% jq '.original_timestamp |= (. / 1000 | floor | todate)' <<EOJ
{
  "cluster_name": "c",
  "definition_name": "hive_metastore_process",
  "firmness": "HARD",
  "latest_timestamp": 1498716914911,
  "maintenance_state": "OFF",
  "original_timestamp": 1498716914911,
  "service_name": "HIVE",
  "state": "CRITICAL"
}
EOJ
{
  "cluster_name": "c",
  "definition_name": "hive_metastore_process",
  "firmness": "HARD",
  "latest_timestamp": 1498716914911,
  "maintenance_state": "OFF",
  "original_timestamp": "2017-06-29T06:15:14Z",
  "service_name": "HIVE",
  "state": "CRITICAL"
}
%
```

Comment: I do not want to use jq instead I want to do usisng UNIX command, can you help how to convert timestamp to date format using UNIX command ?

Comment: There aren't any standard unix commands that can parse json.  If your input is very well formed, you could probably construct something with awk.